# How to find the bandwidth of the transmitted M-FSK signal?

Tags: digital-communications, qpsk, bpsk, fsk, communication-standard

I'm tried to find the solution, but I failed.

my question in the figure below, and the correct answer it's shown at the end of Figure.
[image]

I'm using this formula but the answer is not correct!
[image]
Is there another solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula you would arrive at 5Rs. Pay attention to the spacing given in the formula and the spacing of your actual carriers. The 4-orthogonal FSK system is not at the minimum frequency separation; you could actually fit in 3 more carriers that would still be orthogonal and thus have the same bandwidth as a 7-orthogonal FSK system.

Comment: Can you explain more, I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: @Abdallah_98 Look at $\Delta F$ in the formula, and look at $\Delta F$ for the carriers you actually have.